# AuthFailure for allocating EC2-VPC ip address using boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-2.7, boto

I wrote a script in python for rotating ip address of Amazon EC2 instance everyday and I'm releasing the old ip address as well, the command works perfectly but sometimes the script failed with the following error response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Errors>
      <Error>
         <Code>AuthFailure</Code>
         <Message>The address '52.87.82.238' does not belong to you.</Message>
      </Error>
   </Errors>
   <RequestID>0484b5ed-3ad9-4f86-82e6-652e6b09e072</RequestID>
</Response>
```

when I checked the AWS console I found that old ip address is disassociated from instance but still appear in Elastic ips section.

Note: when I check that ip address in out `52.87.82.238` and release it manually and re-run the code again everything is ok.
The failure occur every month

Any help on that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I just solve the issue , it seems that I need to make filter when I listing the ip addresses for instances like below :

filters={'instance-id': instance_id, 'domain': 'vpc', }